# Nintendo Network ID requirement

Tags: region-lock, nintendo-network-id

Which regions are accepted by Nintendo Network ID? I live in Malaysia and they don't allow me to join the network ID. Any idea or list of which countries are accepted?

I have tried it a few times and they don't allow me to join.

Answer (score 1):

I'm in Thailand, which is not on the list of Nintendo ID regions either. I think this list only includes regions that Nintendo targets with that version of the console.

I bought US versions of 3DS and WiiU. In NNID, I chose Canada and found a Canadian zip code on the internet.

Comment: what happen if i type a zip code (that not in our country) when purchase a dlc and how can i check which zone that i buy my nintendo 3ds ?

Comment: In thai can use canada alberta with zip code T6J6S2 to use thai debit or credit card

but i don't know about malaysia card 

if you don't sure select US region and US Zipcode (some zipcode is no tax)

Comment: and buy Eshop card on web to redeem point

Comment: So at the option i need to change the region to US then only create a nnid account ?

Comment: to create nnid if you don't have your region you will select other in 3ds console to create

Comment: should i need to check my area see whether the same region that i create to buy the eshop card ( I'm not using credit card )or the eshop cards are global i can get it whatever region i want ???

Comment: Eshop card in my country is work for US region and don't work for canada if you what to use Eshop let try to set at alaska because this area is no tax

Comment: So basically i just need to change my setting to USA and get the same region Eshop card to buy stuff?

Comment: ...I wonder if it would accept `H0H0H0` as a Canadian zip code.